# Are $A$ and $A^\top$ similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ a square matrix with entries in $K$. Then A and $A^\top$ have the same characteristic polynomial. What do we know about similarity? Do you have an example where $A$ and $A^\top$ are not similar?

Comment: They are similar, however to prove it (at least how I know to prove it) using the Jordan form of $A$ and $A^t$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94599/a-matrix-is-similar-to-its-transpose

Comment: The easiest proof is perhaps via Smith normal form. If $P(\lambda)(\lambda I-A)Q(\lambda)=D(\lambda)$ then $Q(\lambda)^T(\lambda I-A^T)P(\lambda)^T=D(\lambda)^T=D(\lambda)$ so $A$ and $A^T$ share the invariant factors (on the diagonal of $D(\lambda)$), thus, are similar.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $A^T$ are necessarily similar.  To show this, it suffices to note that
$$
\dim \ker [(A - \lambda I)^k] = \dim \ker [(A^T - \lambda I)^k]
$$
for all $\lambda$ taken from the algebraic closure of $K$ and all $k \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: This shows the fact for algebraic closed fields. For arbitrary fields $K$ it's left to show that the matrix $S$ with $A=S^{-1}A^\top S$ has its entries in $K$ instead of $\bar K$.

Comment: You mean that a suitable $S$ with entries in $K$ exists.  Yes, it is necessary to make that observation.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to note that 
$$
\{S: SA - A^TS = 0\}
$$
is a linear subspace

Comment: See the argument given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/62591/81360)