# Show that $A$ is similar to $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Assume $A$ is diagonalizable. Show that $A$ is similar to $A^T$

Any help would be very appreciated. I know for a matrix to be diagonalizable it has to be a square matrix so the # of rows and columns stay the same for $A^T$.

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/94599) which considers the general case (no need that $A$ is diagonalizable).

Comment: $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $A^T$ because $det(A−λI)=det(AT−λI)$ And then from ( if it is true) math.stackexchange.com/questions/556257/… we have that if two matrices have the same set of eigenvalues they are similar under condition that all eigenvalues are distinct.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:
$$A=PDP^{-1}$$
$$A^T=(P^{-1})^TDP^T$$
Express $D$ in terms of $A^T$ and substitute to the first equation.

Note that $\left(P^{-1}\right)^{T}=\left(P^T\right)^{-1}.$ It is also commonly denoted by $P^{-T}$.

Comment: [+1] I had no idea that such a simple proof is possible...

Comment: Just a little thing: it might be better to write $P^{-T}$ as $(P^{-1})^T$.

Answer (score 3):

Given that $A$ is diagonalizable, so there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $$D=P^{-1}AP$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
So we obtain $$A=PDP^{-1}$$
Then $$A^T=(PDP^{-1})^T=(P^{-1})^TD^TP^T=(P^{-1})^TDP^T=(P^{-1})^T(P^{-1}AP)P^T=Q^{-1}AQ$$
where $Q=PP^T$ is an invertible matrix.
So by definition, $A$ is similar to $A^T$.