# Prove that every real-valued matrix is similar to its transpose ( w/o using complex numbers field)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

As in the title of question, I'd like to ask for a proof of the following statement:

*For every real-valued $n\times n$ matrix $A$ there exists an invertible, real-valued $n \times n$ matrix $P$ such, that $A = P^{-1} A^T P$.*

My professor told me that it is entirely possible to do it without using whole complex numbers apparatus. However, I'm not sure how to do it since $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.

I know that similar topics have already appeared, i.e. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94599/a-matrix-is-similar-to-its-transpose) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62497/matrix-is-conjugate-to-its-own-transpose). None of them, unfortunately, fully answers my question.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write  $A = P^{-1}A^T P$?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: [Marc's Answer from your second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/596842/318831) does not rely on the algebraic closure. Is your problem with it not being familiar with the Smith Normal Form?

Comment: [This was asked here as well](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122345/an-n-times-n-matrix-a-is-similar-to-its-transpose-a-top-elementary-pr) and it's been concluded that the Smith Normal form is the way to go @UsernameUnknown. It seems unlikely that there is going to be any simpler method.