# Prove or disprove matrix $A$ and $A^T$ is Matrix congruence?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

> prove or disprove
>
> for any matrix $A$ and $A^T$ are Matrix congruence?

This problem is my  Suddenly thought today .

I know this fact:

if $A$ is symmetry matrix,then
$A$ and $A^T$ are  matrix congruence.

Now this problem not tell us  $A$ is symmetry.

so How prove it? Thank you  very much

Comment: $A$ and $A^t$ are similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62497/matrix-is-conjugate-to-its-own-transpose

Comment: No,But even $A$ and $A^T$ are similar,we can't have $A$ and $A^T$ are Matrix congruence.

Comment: What do you mean by "are matrix congruence"? By definition $A$ and $B$ are similar if there exists invertible $P$ with $PAP^{-1}=B$, is that not what you mean?

Comment: The fact that if $A$ is symmetric then $A$ and $A^T$ "are matrix congruence" does not help us much, since they are _the same_.

Comment: I think the OP meant to ask whether $A$ and $A^T$ are always congruent to each other, i.e. there exists a nonsignular matrix $C$ such that $C^TAC=A^T$. He/she is not talking about similarity and we don't require that $C^T=C^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is affirmative over any field. See

> Dragomir Ž. Đoković, Khakim D. Ikramov (2002), *[A square matrix is congruent to its transpose](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869302001266)*, Journal of Algebra, 257(1): 97-105.

When the field is complex, not only is $A$ congruent to $A^T$, it is $\ast$-congruent to $A^T$ as well. See

> Roger A. Horn, Vladimir V. Sergeichuk (2004), *[Congruences of a square matrix and its transpose](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379504001533)*, Linear Algebra and its Applications, 389: 347-353. (Also available from [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2489) .)