# Let A a diagonalizable matrix. Show that $A$ and $A^{t}$ are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  A a diagonalizable matrix. Show that $A$ and $A^{t}$ are similar.

Comment: What's the transpose of a diagonal matrix? what happens when you pick a matrix similar to $A$ and transpose it?

Comment: Do you know what the elements on the main diagonal in the diagonal form of $\;A\;$ are?

Answer (score 1):

This [result holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62497/18880) true without the hypothesis that $A$ is diagonalizable. However, given that this hypothesis is nevertheless given, one may assume you are supposed to show this using an auxiliary result, namely that if $A$ is similar to$~B$, then $A^t$ is similar to$~B^t$, which is not hard to show. This will then allow you to reduce the proof to a special case where you replace $A$ by a special matrix similar to $A$, and for which the result is easier. Can you guess what that special matrix might be?

Answer (score 0):

Note that any two diagonalizable matrices are similar if and only if they have the same eigenvalues (including multiplicity).  Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then it is an eigenvalue of $A^T$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact shown by Omnomnomnom :

Recall : A square matrix and its transpose have the same determinant.

$\det(A^{T} - \lambda I) = \det((A - \lambda I)^{T})  = \det (A - \lambda I)$

It's easy to see they have the same eigenvalue.