# $A$ and $A^t$ are conjugate?

Tags: linear-algebra

[It is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62497/matrix-is-conjugate-to-its-own-transpose) that every square matrix $A$ is conjugate to its transpose. When I heard this first time, the way I tried to prove this is the following way:

**(1)** let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Fix a basis $\mathcal{B}_V$ of $V$. Then there exists a linear transformation $T\colon V\rightarrow V$, whose matrix w.r.t $\mathcal{B}_V$ is $A$.

**(2)** Then what about $A^t$? It is known that if 
$$\begin{array}{rl}
V^*=& \mbox{dual space of } V,\\
\mathcal{B}_V^*=& \mbox{dual basis of } \mathcal{B}_V\\
T^*\colon V^*\rightarrow V^*=& \mbox{adjoint of the transformation } $T$, 
\end{array}$$
then $A^t$ is the matrix of the *adjoint* transformation $T^*$.

**(3)** Further we know that, since $V$ is finite dimensional,  $V\cong V^*$.

BUT, I couldn't proceed further, towards the proof of *$A$ and $A^t$ are conjugate.* I don't know whether this way can be proceeded towards proof. Can you help me, to decide whether this is a right way?

Comment: Here's a hint: Suppose you start with $K=\Bbb C$. What tool do you have at your disposal now?

Comment: This result annoys me (and probably others) with its simple formulation and lack of a comparably nice proof. Short of module theory over PIDs (which, to some extent, is a coordinate-free rewriting of what @TedShifrin is suggesting), no real "explanations" for this result have been seen.