# Are real antisymmetric matrices orthogonally similar to their transposes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a real antisymmetric matrix. Is it true that $A$ must be  **orthogonally** similar to its transpose (i.e to $-A$)?

**Note:** It's known that [every matrix is similar to its transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62497/matrix-is-conjugate-to-its-own-transpose).
It's also known, that in general, [**not** every real matrix is orthogonally similar to its transpose](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379507002856/1-s2.0-S0024379507002856-main.pdf?_tid=c617ad7c-b312-11e5-923c-00000aacb360&acdnat=1451933071_005506944a39984c69d4268612ed4832).

However, in the example given in the reference above, $A$ is not antisymmetric.

Comment: In general, an antisymmetric $A$ will be *unitarily* similar to its transpose.  Not sure about orthogonal similarity, though.

Comment: It seems it is true for $2\times 2$ matrices (if I have not misunderstood the question). In general, we want $A$ to be real and such that $A^T=-A$. We want to see whether there exist an orthogonal matrix $O$ ($O O^T=O^T O=\mathbf{1}$) such that
$$
A = -OAO^T\ .
$$
(continue)

Comment: Now take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \alpha\\
-\alpha & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
($\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha\neq 0$) and parametrize the $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix as
$$
O=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & -\cos\theta\\
\end{pmatrix}\ .
$$
Now, the matrix $A+OAO^T$ is indeed equal to the null matrix $\forall\theta$. So *any* orthogonal matrix $2\times 2$ with $\det O =-1$ does the job. Not sure about general size, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. All real skew-symmetric matrices are orthogonally similar to their [*real Jordan forms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) (see, e.g. Corollary 2.5.14 of Horn and Johnson's [*Matrix Analysis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&pg=PA100&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)). So, the conclusion follows from either one of the following two observations:

1. The transpose of a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric. Hence both $A$ and $A^T$ are orthogonally similar to the same real Jordan form.
2. The $2\times2$ skew-symmetric block $\pmatrix{0&-y\\ y&0}$ (that appears in the real Jordan form of a skew-symmetric matrix) is permutation-similar to its transpose.