# Determining a matrix from its characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, galois-theory, systems-of-equations, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n}(K)$, where $K$ is a field. Then, we can obtain the characteristic polynomial of $A$ by simply taking $p(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I_n)$, which give us something like

$$p(\lambda) = (-1)^n\lambda^n + (-1)^{n-1}(\text{tr } A)\lambda^{n-1} +  \cdots + \det A$$

Now, how can we obtain the matrix $A$ knowing the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: There is not a bijection between Matrices and characteristic polynomials!

Comment: No. Two matrices sharing identical characteristics need not even be similar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any two similar matrices $B = P A P^{-1}$ will have the same characteristic polynomial.  Also $A$ and $A^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

While the matrix $A$ which has a given characteristic polynomial is not unique, it is often convenient to choose an upper [Hessenberg matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix) called the (Frobenius) [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) or its (lower Hessenberg) transpose.

That is, the $n\times n$ matrix:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_0 \\
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_1 \\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & -c_{n-1}
 \end{bmatrix} $$

has characteristic polynomial $p(x) = x^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1 x + c_0$.

One approach to finding the roots of a polynomial is to apply eigenvalue solvers to the companion matrix for the polynomial.

Comment: For your second sentence: actually $A$ and $A^T$ are [always similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/62497), so you are not saying anything new really. But it is true that it is easier to see that they have the same characteristic polynomial than that they are similar.

Comment: In fact, so many companion matrices with special properties can be constructed, depending on how the polynomial is represented. There are companion matrices corresponding to polynomials represented in the Lagrange, Newton, Bernstein, orthogonal, etc. bases. There is a lot of literature on this subject.

Comment: @J.M. Could you advise me a book or an article about it?

Comment: @Victor, see e.g. [this article](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~rcorless/frames/PAPERS/PABV/CMP.pdf). Searching for "generalized companion matrix" or "comrade matrix" will turn up more references.

Answer (score 14):

If $A$ and $S$ are $n\times n$ matrices, with $S$ invertible, then $A$ and $SAS^{-1}$ have the same characteristic polynomial. But even non similar matrices can have the same characteristic polynomial: consider
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So you cannot find *the* matrix having a given characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Ok. Now, just like a basis of a vector space which "generates" all the vectors. Is it possible to establish the same thing here? I mean, can the characteristic polynomial generate all those matrices? I'm thinking that could play a similar role as the basis... but I don't know how to write the idea and if it has sense

Comment: @Victor, are you familiar with the concept of a Jordan normal form?

Comment: @J.M. Not really... I've taken a linear algebra course but we haven't studied what you mentioned. Does it solve my question?

Comment: @Victor Yes; a polynomial $f(X)$ determines a finite number of matrices in Jordan form having $f(X)$ as characteristic polynomial. Any matrix having $f(X)$ as characteristic polynomial is similar to one of those Jordan forms, in the sense that it is $SJS^{-1}$ for $J$ one of those matrices determined before.

Comment: @Victor, the point here would be that these three matrices have different JNFs (they are in fact already in JNF), and these clearly reveal that they are not similar. In particular, only the first matrix is diagonalizable. Anyway, you'll want to wait until you get taught the JNF in your courses.

Comment: It sounds interesting! Many thanks!

Comment: What other properties are shared by matrices with the same Jordan NF, do they , e.g., have the same determinant , are they all invertible, etc?

Comment: @MSIS It's an equivalent condition to being similar.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can determine the matrix from its characteristic polynomial because the characteristic polynomial is determined by $n$ numbers and the matrix by $n^2$ numbers.