# Finding normal operator matrix from characteristic polynomial

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-algebras

Let $ A \in L ( \mathbb{C}^4) $ be a normal operator with characteristic polynomial $ k_{A} = (\lambda - 1)^2 * (\lambda - 2)^2$. Is then the matrix for the operator just a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues on the diagonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $A$ is unitarily diagonizable, as are all normal operators (see [this wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator)), though it may not itself be *diagonal* in the initial form it is presented; since the characteristic polynomial of $A$,

$k_A = (x - 1)^2(x - 2)^2, \tag 1$

has two zeroes $1$ and $2$, each of multiplicity $2$, it follows that there is a basis of $\Bbb C^4$ in which the matrix of $A$ takes the form

$[A] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}. \tag 2$

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. The operator is certainly - as it is normal, then diagonalizable - *similar* to a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Comment: But how do I find the operators matrix then?

Comment: You can't determine the operator from the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658106/determining-a-matrix-from-its-characteristic-polynomial