# Find $z_1^5 + z_2^5 + z_3^5$ given that $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ are the roots of $z^3 -z -1 = 0$

Tags: polynomials

Hello everyone I have the polynomial $z^3 -z -1 = 0$ and $z_1 , z_2 , z_3$ are the roots of this polynomial.

How can I find $z_1^5 + z_2^5 + z_3^5 ?$

I know that $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 0 , z_1 \cdot z_2 + z_1 \cdot z_3 + z_2 \cdot z_3 = -1 , z_1z_2z_3 = 1$

Comment: Have you tried Cardano's method for solving a depressed cubic?

Comment: No. What is it?

Comment: I will post an answer. It is quite simple.

Comment: Thank you Micha!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple slightly tedious method:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and note 
that $\chi_A(z) = z^3-z-1$. Hence the sum of the $5$th powers of the roots is given by
$\operatorname{tr} A^5 = 5$.

Comment: Rabbits out of a hat.

Comment: That matrix is my companion :-).

Comment: I didn't learn matrix but thanks.

Comment: @YvesDaoust's method is nice.

Comment: Excellent (+1).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658106/determining-a-matrix-from-its-characteristic-polynomial

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

For all roots,
$$z^5=z^2z^3=z^3+z^2=z^2+z+1.$$

Expand $(z_1+z_2+z_3)^2.$

Comment: @Yehonatan: what is $z^3$ ?

Comment: I didn't tell you i tell cooper

Comment: And what do you mean at what is $z^3$ ?

Comment: @Yehonatan: observe your problem.

Comment: +1: Nice observation.

Comment: did you mean the coefficient of $z^3$?

Comment: @Yehonatan: last hint: $z^3=z+1$.

Answer (score 2):

$z_1^3=z_1+1,z_2^3=z_2+1$

$z_1z_2z_3 = 1\rightarrow z_1z_2(z_1+z_2)=-1$

$z_1^5 + z_2^5 + z_3^5=z_1^5 + z_2^5 - (z_1+z_2)^5=
-(5z_1^4z_2+10z_1^3z_2^2+10z_1^2z_2^3+5z_1z_2^4)=-5z_1z_2(z_1^3+2z_1^2z_2+2z_1z_2^2+z_2^3)=-5z_1z_2(z_1+z_2+2+2z_1z_2(z_1+z_2))=-5z_1z_2(z_1+z_2+2-2)=-5z_1z_2(z_1+z_2)= 5 $

Answer (score -1):

Your equation is of the form:
$$y^3+Ay=B$$
where:
$$y=z,A=-1,B=1$$
Now substitute:
$$3st=A$$
$$s^3-t^3=B$$
Then solve for:
$$y=s-t$$
Can you find the roots now?
Once you have these roots, you can perform whatever operations on them you like.

P.S. You can find more information about Cardano's method [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/).

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Cardano is probably the worst method to use here. Think about raising the roots to the fifth power !

Comment: @YvesDaoust You can raise any number to the fifth power using a calculator with ease. What are you on about?

Comment: If a CAS or a numerical solver is allowed, there is no point doing the exercise. There is a solution *without* computing the roots.