# Commuting space dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

If $C(A) = \{X\in M_n(\mathbb{K}),~XA = AX\}$, I showed that $\dim C(A) \geq n$, also $C(A) = \mathbb{K}[A]$ iff $\mu_A = \chi_A$. If the equivalence is verified, we have $$\dim C(A) = \dim\mathbb{K}[A] = \deg \mu_A = \deg \chi_A = n.$$ Is it true that $\dim C(A) = n$ implies the equivalence ?

My guess is that it's false, but I can't seem to find any counter example. I would need $A$ such that $\mu_A\ne \chi_A$, but with $\dim C(A) = n$.

I recall that $\chi_A(X)=\det(XI_n-A)$ and $\mu_A$ is the minimal polynomial such that $\mu_A(A) = 0$.

Comment: Please make your post a bit more self-contained. For those of us who don't know, what are $\mu_A$ and $\chi_A$?

Comment: I couldn't resist correcting... presumably... "commuting" to "computing".

Comment: @paulgarrett Commuting is actually probably correct as the space $C(A)$ is the set of matrices which commute with $A$.

Comment: @Fishbane, ah, you're right! My bad! Thanks! I'll repair it... :)

Comment: Can anyone say how did you show $\text{dim }C(A)\geq n$?

Comment: @MasonRashford I showed it first for triangularizable matrixes $A =T$ (see the equality $XT-TX = 0$ as a set of equations and variables). For the general case, I used an extension $\mathbb{K} \subseteq\mathbb{L}$ where $A$ is triangularizable, and worked a bit to show that $\dim_\mathbb{L} C_\mathbb{L} =\dim_\mathbb{K} C_\mathbb{K} \geq n$.

Comment: Can you help me with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801034/proving-the-dimension-of-the-commutant-space-of-a-n-times-n-matrix-is-greater) please? I also have a solution verification question at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is true that $\dim C(A) = n$ implies that $\mu_A$ and $\chi_A$ coincide. Equivalently, if $\mu_A \neq \chi_A$, then $\dim C(A) > n$. It is easiest to see this by appealing to the algebraic closure of $\Bbb K$ and using the Jordan canonical form (cf. *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson, Theorem 3.2.4.2 and its proof, for instance), but here is an attempt to avoid algebraic closures.

To understand the relationship between $A$ and $C(A)$, it is useful to consider the [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) of $A$. We can suppose without loss of generality that $A$ is in this canonical form; that is, we stipulate the following:

- $A$ has the block-diagonal form $A = \operatorname{diag}(A_1,A_2, \dots, A_k)$,
- For each $j = 1,\dots,k$, $A_j$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) associated with the polynomial $p_j(x)$,
- The polynomials satisfy the divisibility condition $p_j \mid p_{j+1}$ for each $j = 1,\dots,k$.

The polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_k$ are sometimes referred to as the [invariant factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor) of $A$. The last of these factors, $p_k$, is the minimal polynomial of $A$, and the characteristic polynomial is the product of these factors.  In fact, this level of detail is more than we strictly need. Let us simply write that $A$ has the block form
$$
A = \pmatrix{P & 0\\0 & Q},
$$
where $Q$ (i.e. $A_k$) is the companion matrix associated with the minimal polynomial of $A$ and $P$ satisfies $p(Q) = 0$ for some polynomial $p$ (i.e. $p_{k-1}$) satisfying $p \mid \mu_A$. It suffices to show that $\dim C(A) > \dim C(P) + \dim C(Q)$, since we already know that
$$
\dim C(P) + \dim C(Q) \geq n_P + n_Q = n.
$$
To that end, we note that the set of matrices of the form
$$
X = \pmatrix{X_1&0\\0&X_2}
$$
such that $X_1 \in C(P)$ and $X_2 \in C(Q)$ are elements of $C(A)$, and that the matrices of this form constitute a dimension-$[\dim C(P) + \dim C(Q)]$ subspace of $C(A)$. Thus, it suffices to find a matrix $X$ in $C(A)$ that is not of this form.

Write
$$
X = \pmatrix{X_{11} & X_{12}\\ X_{21} & X_{22}}.
$$
The condition that $AX = XA$ amounts to the following conditions:
$$
PX_{11} = X_{11}P, \quad P X_{12} = X_{12} Q, \quad Q X_{21} = X_{21} P, \quad Q X_{22} = X_{22}Q,
$$
so it suffices to find a non-zero $X_{12}$ satisfying $PX_{12} = X_{12}Q$. In the case that $p(x)$ has a linear factor, this is trivial: take $X_{12} = vw^T$ where $v,w$ are non-zero vectors such that $Pv = \lambda v$ and $w^TQ = \lambda w$.

For the remaining cases, we have the following.

> **Claim:** Let $f(x)$ be a degree-$d$ (monic) irreducible factor of $p(x)$. Let $v$ denote any non-zero element of $\ker(f(P))$ and $w$ any non-zero element of $\ker f(Q^\top)$. Let $M$ denote [an invertible matrix such that $M^{-1}C_f M = C_f^\top$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254896/81360) (or in fact, any non-zero matrix for which $C_f M = MC_f^\top$). Then the matrix
> $$
> Z = \underbrace{\pmatrix{v & Pv & \cdots P^{d-1}v}}_{Z_1}
> M
> \underbrace{\pmatrix{w^\top \\ w^\top Q \\ \vdots \\ w^\top Q^{d-1} }}_{Z_2} = \sum_{j=0}^{d-1} P^{j}vMw^\top Q^{j}
> $$
> satisfies $PZ = ZQ$.

*Proof:* We have

\begin{align}
P(Z_1 M Z_2) &= (Z_1C_f) M Z_2
\\ & = Z_1 (C_f M) Z_2
\\ & = Z_1 (M C_f^\top) Z_2
\\ & = Z_1 M (C_f^\top Z_2)
\\ & = Z_1 M (Z_2 Q) = (Z_1 M Z_2)Q.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much ! Is there a way to see this without Froebenius reduction ?

Comment: @Rafaël I don't think that there is any approach that works without **some kind** of reduction, be that Frobenius-form, Jordan canonical form, or otherwise.