# Polar decomposition and transpose similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Is there any manner to prove that an inversible real matrix is conjugate to its transpose using the polar decomposition ? This would be, in this particular case, a much more simpler proof than using invariants in the general case.

Comment: What do you mean, "conjugate to its transpose"? Do you mean, $A^\top = \overline{A}$, where $\overline{A}$ is the matrix formed by taking complex conjugates of each entry? If so, this is equivalent to being Hermitian, and is certainly not true for general invertable matrices.

Comment: No, I meant $$P^{-1}AP=A^T$$ for some invertible matrix P

Comment: Good to know. For what it's worth, I would have used the word "similar" instead.

Comment: @Tig There's no way to make use of the polar decomposition for this proof that I know of or can think of. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62497/81360) for a few options for how to go about this proof. Indeed, the fastest approach is to use some kind of invariant or canonical form.